# Inject OkHttp using dagger2 in AndroidTest class for regestering OkHttp3IdlingResource

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, dagger-2

I have an app built with Retorift2 + Dagger2. I started to write Android UI tests using Espresso.
To wait for a netwoking calls I need to register an IdlingResource. I have added dependency to [OkHttp3IdlingResource](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource).

I need to Inject a OkHttp in my test class, but as AppComponent is not in the same source directory so I can't just add

```
void inject(RegistrationLoginUiTest activity);
```

To my component.

How can I get OkHttp from the dependency graph into my test class?

Is the only way to create TestAppComponent and swap it with the AppComponent?

Comment: add in `build.gradle` file dependencies: `androidTestCompile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'`

Comment: then use your `provide...` methods. Just after `inject` set like this `OkHtttp ok = ....inject(RegistrationLoginUiTest activity).provideOkHttpCLient()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out that in any case if I want to inject test class I should create TestAppComponent where I should add line:

```
void inject(RegistrationLoginUiTest activity);
```

And then swap TestAppComponent with AppComponent